# Unable to scrape all the urls available in different depth out of some json content

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse all the value of urls available in different depth within some json content. I'm attaching [a file](https://filebin.net/00t7ezbz7uspwj13) containing the urls in different depth for your consideration.

This is how they are structured (truncated):

```
{'hasSub': True,
 'navigationTitle': 'Products',
 'nodeName': 'products',
 'pages': [{'hasSub': True,
            'navigationTitle': 'Enclosures',
            'nodeName': 'PG0002SCHRANK1',
            'pages': [{'hasSub': True,
                       'navigationTitle': 'Hygienic Design',
                       'nodeName': 'PG0125SCHRANK1',
                       'pages': [{'hasSub': False,
                                  'navigationTitle': 'Hygienic Design Terminal '
                                                     'box HD',
                                  'nodeName': 'PRO0130',
                                  'target': '_self',
                                  'url': '/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1/PG0125SCHRANK1/PRO0130'},
                                 {'hasSub': False,
                                  'navigationTitle': 'Hygienic Design Compact '
                                                     'enclosure HD, '
                                                     'single-door',
                                  'nodeName': 'PRO0131',
                                  'target': '_self',
                                  'url': '/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1/PG0125SCHRANK1/PRO0131'},
```

If I consider the above content, the output I'm after:

```
/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1/PG0125SCHRANK1/PRO0130
/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1/PG0125SCHRANK1/PRO0131
```

The script that I've written to produce the json content:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://www.rittal.com/.rest/nav/menu/tree?'
params = {
    'path': 'com',
    'locale': 'en',
    'deep': '10'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    r = s.get(url,params=params)
    pprint(r.json()['pages'][0])
```

> How can I scrape all the urls from different depth out of the json content?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is recurse over the JSON. This is the best way to handle the differing depth of URLs.

The following recursion will retrieve the deepest URLs by recursing over the JSON.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://www.rittal.com/.rest/nav/menu/tree'
params = {
    'path': 'com',
    'locale': 'en',
    'deep': '10'
}

def recurse(data):
    if 'pages' in data:
        for page in data['pages']:
            recurse(page)
    elif 'url' in data and data['url'].startswith('/com-en/'):
        urls.append(data['url'])

urls = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    r = s.get(url, params=params).json()
    recurse(r)
    pprint(urls)
```

This is how it works:

- Recursive case - if there are pages at the current level, then recurse for each `page` at the current level
- Base case - if a URL appears at the current level, then append it to a list of URLs

Also, if you switch out the `elif` for an `if`, it will give you *all* the URLs at *any* level.

**Update:** It seems there are 2 rouge URLs in that JSON. In particular, one is `https://www.eplan-software.com/solutions/eplan-platform/` and another is blank! As such, I've added the condition `data['url'].startswith('/com-en/')` to only append the URLs which fit the expected pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems I've found a solution elsewhere to fetch all the available links out of any nested json.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://www.rittal.com/.rest/nav/menu/tree?'
params = {
    'path': 'com',
    'locale': 'en',
    'deep': '10'
}

def json_extract(obj, key):
    arr = []

    def extract(obj, arr, key):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            for k, v in obj.items():
                if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                    extract(v, arr, key)
                elif k == key:
                    arr.append(v)
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for item in obj:
                extract(item, arr, key)
        return arr

    values = extract(obj, arr, key)
    return values

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    r = s.get(url, params=params).json()
    for item in json_extract(r,'url'):
        print(item)
```

Number of links the script produces is around 3500.